# How do you get simple_form to use the base class for urls and not the subclass?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

Whenever I use simple_form_for(), it defaults to "my_subclasses_path" rather than "my_base_classes_path". How can I tell it to not use the subclass?

In my case, I have a User object, but also many subclasses. I want to use the standard user urls as all the subclasses work the same for these forms.

In addition, I want to stop simple_form from naming the properties after the subclass. For example, if the subclass is "Admin", I want the submitted parameters to be "params[:user]" and not "params[:admin]".

I find the above to be REALLY odd because the form actually says "user[first_name]" and NOT "admin[first_name]" - but simple_form seems to want to make it params[:admin] anyway.

Basically, subclasses are causing simple_for to not behave properly. I wish there was an option like

```
base_class => 'User'
```

That would handle all of these things.

Comment: I still need help with this one. This one is driving me nuts actually. For example, if you are an Admin, which is a subclass of user, and then go to edit your profile... it will assume that you want params[:admin] rather than params[:user]. This is obviously really crappy because it'll be different for all the user types on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the `:url` option to `simple_form_for`.

eg.: `simple_form_for(@admin, :url => users_path)`

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not enough. It will still try and name all the properties to admin[first_name] instead of user[first_name]

Comment: Use the default rails form builder and see if it solve your problem

Answer (score 19):

If you pass in the :url option as rafaelfranca suggests, along with the :as option, it should work correctly. For example:

```
simple_form_for(@admin, :url => user_path(@admin), :as => :user)
```

This gives me the correct form action and parameters (e.g. user[name] instead of admin[name]).